# iptables - masqueraded NAT has delayed first hop in traceroute

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, nat, traceroute

I'm just in the process of setting up my Linux (Debian-based) router with a PPPoE connection via an ADSL/PPPoA -> PPPoE bridge. The connection works perfectly on the router itself but a traceroute through the NAT for some reason takes a long time to get the result of the first hop (to the NAT).

The majority of the time the result of the hop will just be * * * but sometimes the hop does show up and there's a long delay before it tries the second hop.

Here's when it doesn't show the hop at all:

```
CallumsMacBookAir:~ Callum$ traceroute google.co.uk
traceroute: Warning: google.co.uk has multiple addresses; using 173.194.41.95
traceroute to google.co.uk (173.194.41.95), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * * //LONG DELAY
 2  lo0-central10.ptn-ag03.plus.net (195.166.128.192)  22.578 ms  19.925 ms  20.990 ms
 3  link-a-central10.ptn-gw01.plus.net (212.159.2.136)  19.574 ms  19.786 ms  19.343 ms
 4  xe-5-3-0.ptw-cr01.plus.net (212.159.0.108)  19.540 ms  18.947 ms  25.387 ms
 5  72.14.222.97 (72.14.222.97)  19.911 ms  19.706 ms  19.512 ms
 6  209.85.246.244 (209.85.246.244)  19.423 ms  19.455 ms  19.655 ms
 7  72.14.238.51 (72.14.238.51)  20.234 ms  24.666 ms  20.076 ms
 8  lhr08s01-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.41.95)  19.168 ms  19.518 ms  19.659 ms
```

Sometimes it does respond in the first hop but there's still an asterisk:

```
CallumsMacBookAir:~ Callum$ traceroute google.co.uk
traceroute: Warning: google.co.uk has multiple addresses; using 173.194.41.95
traceroute to google.co.uk (173.194.41.95), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.253 (192.168.0.253)  0.770 ms *  0.800 ms
//LONG DELAY IN HERE
 2  lo0-central10.ptn-ag03.plus.net (195.166.128.192)  20.301 ms  22.958 ms  32.719 ms
 3  link-a-central10.ptn-gw01.plus.net (212.159.2.136)  19.142 ms  19.417 ms  18.527 ms
 4  xe-5-3-0.ptw-cr01.plus.net (212.159.0.108)  19.047 ms  18.781 ms  18.887 ms
 5  72.14.222.97 (72.14.222.97)  19.181 ms  19.424 ms  29.965 ms
 6  209.85.246.244 (209.85.246.244)  33.559 ms  19.756 ms  25.363 ms
 7  72.14.238.51 (72.14.238.51)  32.010 ms  19.753 ms  19.042 ms
 8  lhr08s01-in-f31.1e100.net (173.194.41.95)  19.618 ms  19.730 ms *
```

Is there any way to make the iptables router respond to the traceroute properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be the router had 2 virtual interfaces on one physical interface. Problem was solved by getting iptables to use only the virtual interface eth0:0 for the routing.